# XHR 404 with system.js when loading in angular2 module

Tags: angular, module, systemjs

I have been at this for two days now, I can't figure out system.js with angular2. I am trying to load https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal

I followed both directions and read many many posts on system.js but I know I'm not picking something up. The error I get is
:
angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal(…)

index.html

```
    <script src="node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/bundles/ng2-bs3-modal.js"></script>
```

System.js

```
    <script>
  System.config({
    packages: {
      defaultJSExtensions: true,
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
      'ng2-bs3-modal': 'node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal'
    }
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of Angular2 you are using?

Comment: "angular2@2.0.0-beta.7", from my package.json. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong with paths/mapping

Comment: Angular loads fine btw, no problems toying around with the apps I have been building

Comment: Verify your index.html with this- https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal-demo-systemjs/blob/master/index.html You may be missing js files like angular2-polyfills.js etc

Comment: No good, I just don't see it tried for a very long time, http://pastebin.com/kH6ATMUN, I restored it back to before I tried importing the new blob

Comment: Any reason you are using beta 7 and not latest RC version?

Comment: I have bought many classes on Udemy and that is what the class is using, thank you for your help on this